# I am trying to authenticate the the USER model for Register and Login API in Django REST framework. I am getting the following error msg

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

I have tried all the available internet solutions, added the

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

But nothing worked in my favor. I am adding the serilizers.py and api.py files below. Please review them and tell me if there is some other way to fix this.
Following is the serializers.py file code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta: 
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

# Register Serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

  def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])

    return user

# Login Serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  username = serializers.CharField()
  password = serializers.CharField()

  def validate(self, data):
    user = authenticate(**data)
    if user and user.is_active:
      return user
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")
```

api.py is given as:

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer

# Register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
  
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": token
    })

# Login API
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
  serializer_class = LoginSerializer

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data
    _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
    return Response({
      "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
      "token": token
    })

# Get User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated,
  ]
  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .api import RegisterAPI, LoginAPI, UserAPI
from knox import views as knox_views

urlpatterns = [
  path('api/auth/', include('knox.urls')),
  path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
  path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout')
]
```

Please help me solve the issue. I am unable to make any post request on Postman and without Register, Login API won't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the API public, you need to override your permissions in your settings. You should update your Views.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

# Register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    authentication_classes=() # To make sure no check if you send Authorization header to server
    ...
```

Apply for your Login view too.

Comment: I did this but still getting the same error: "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." Plus the register API is working fine but the Login request is generating the error.

Comment: When calling your login API, you need provide request body to include `username` and `password` values. `{"username": "username", "password": "password"}`

Comment: Thank you! It Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Register view to allow non logged in since you have `'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'` as a default permission

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

# Register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
  
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": token
    })
```

Comment: I did this but still getting the same error: "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." Plus the register API is working fine but the Login request is generating the error.